# Is the Father sending the Son a statement unique to the Johannine corpus?

Tags: john, new-testament, christology

In John's Gospel and his letter, the statement that the Father sent the Son is made several times. Two examples:

> that all may honor the Son, just as they honor the Father. Whoever does not honor the Son does not honor the Father who sent him. (John 5:23 ESV)
>
> And we have seen and testify that the Father has sent his Son to be the Savior of the world.
> (1 John 4:1)

While Matthew, Mark, Luke, and Paul have "him" or "God" who sent, I don't see where the specific identification of the one who sent Jesus as "the Father" is made. Is the specific identification of the Father as sending Jesus unique to John? And if so, is there some additional significance John intends?

Comment: If other Evangelists identify God as Father of Jesus, and if they also  say that Jesus is sent by God (cf. for example Matthew 15:24) then what's a problem? What difference is there if I say "god-Zeus sent Athena to Odysseus", or "father sent Athena to Odysseus? It's all the same, for all know that god-Zeus is Athena's father.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili Matthew 15:24 says nothing about the Father. God as Father is in the Pauline corpus and John, but not directly in Matthew, Mark, or Luke.

Comment: You say it well, "not directly", but perfectly clearly and absolutely unambiguously - indirectly. So, my first comment remains as put as initially. Even more, how can you say "not directly" when Jesus teaches Lord's Prayer "Our Father" in Matthew and Luke? Who He is referring to? Some other deity than God the Creator of heaven and earth, the one God of Israel?

Comment: p.s. Or does not He in Luke 2:49 directly call God His "Father"?

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili "Our Father" does not mean the same thing in the Jewish faith as in Christianity. "Our Father" in Judaism is an affirmation of Exodus 4:22, not an acknowledgement of rebirth (John 3) as children of God (John 1:12-13). So instructing a Jewish audience to pray "Our Father..." makes no additional affirmation about the status of Jesus to God or His Father. IOW Jesus could simply be a good Jewish teacher (or Rabbi). I suspect were it not for the claim Christian's make to that prayer, it would still be something a Jewish non-believer in Christ would continue to pray today.

Comment: As to Luke 2:49. Based on John, it means He is calling God His Father as the Christian understands the phrase. But to one who is Jewish, it does not necessarily come across that way. It could be a child's way of understanding their relationship to the LORD as one born of Abraham. Since Luke does not record any of the other statements which make that clear, it is an open question (in Luke-Acts for the non-Christian). My question concerns how the term God as Father differs between the existing Jewish faith (i.e. Israel is My son) and the belief in rebirth as children of God Christians claim.

Comment: I think this is an additional point John makes in the Prologue. John the Baptist was a man sent by God like all previous OT prophets in contrast to the Word who was God sent to become human to save all who believe in His Name. That is, Jesus was not an OT prophet; He was more because God was His Father and so He has equality with God.

Comment: If you want to intentionally relativise the Luke 2:49, who on earth will deter you?! Yet, "MY  Father" is the unique statement, for no prophet has dared to say this; yes, metaphorically, God is "Father" of Israel, but nobody personalises Him with the possessive pronoun "my", which is a scandalous, and as for Jews, even a blasphemous personalisation, as evident in Mark 14:62 also. And sometimes synoptics are no less direct about equal divinity of the Son with the Father(cf. Matthew 11:27) than John is, not to say anything about the pleroma of clearest indirect and implicit evidences for that.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili I think John also identifies this aspect in 8:31-59. It is not simply Jesus is the Son of God; it is also the sons of Abraham are not the Sons of God, if they reject Jesus. As I said, Luke 2:49 and the other references imply what John makes explicit. It is possible some accepted Jesus as Christ but not as **the** Son of God.

Comment: Yes, even the closest disciples often failed to grasp what He really was about (cf. Mark 10:37); You may be right that John could be more outspoken on the point of the adopted sonship through Christ. But the "Our Father" implies just that: "forgive us our trespasses as we forgive those who trespass against us" is impossible without man rising to the status of God, to the sonship of God by adoption, when only Jesus has this Sonship naturally and unbeginnedly, like Father has Fatherhood naturally and unbeginnedly. But no Jew can forgive without Jesus, it cannot be a Jewish prayer, impossible.

Comment: But in sense of the explicitness, you are right: as the Godhead of Jesus is most directly expressed in John, so also the fact that nobody can become a child of God without Jesus' grace, is said most clearly in John. And, again, since according to the Lord's Prayer we are given divine authority to forgive as God forgives us, then we are truly His children and are authorised call Him "Father". The acclamation of God as "Father" denotes thus a novel, divine status of Christians, which Paul calls us being a "new creation".

Comment: p.s. and sorry for writing too long a thread, will be glad to discuss those issues separately on chat option or on e-mail lgigineishvili@yahoo.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me layout the occurrence of the verbs used to send "Christ":

**ἀποστέλλω (apostelló)**

1. Christ sent by an unspecified authority (the Father implied??), Matt 10:40, 15:24, 21:37 (parable), Mark 9:37, 12:6, Luke 4:43, 9:48, 10:16, John 7:28
2. Christ sent by the "Spirit of the Lord", Luke 4:18
3. Christ sent by "God", John 3:17, 6:29, 8:42, Acts 3:20, 26, 1 John 4:9, 10
4. Christ sent by "the Father", John 5:36, 38, 6:57, 10:36, 11:42, 17:3, 8, 18, 21, 23, 25, 20:21, 1 John 4:14.

**πέμπω (pempó)**

1. Christ sent by an unspecified authority (the Father implied??), Luke 20:13 (parable), John 4:34, 5:24, 30, 6:38, 39, 7:16, 18, 28, 33, 8:26, 29, 9:4, 12:44, 45, 13:20, 15:21, 16:5
2. Christ sent by the Spirit, --
3. Christ sent by "God", Rom 8:3
4. Christ sent by "the Father", John 5:23, 37, 44, 8:16, 18, 12:49, 14:24

Thus, we may deduce that, indeed, John is the only NT writer to explicitly specify "the Father" as the one who sent Jesus.  All other writers simply say either "God", leave it implied, or, "the Spirit of God".  John also uses most of these expressions as well.

Note that John also uses the idea of Jesus being sent more often that all other NT writers.  Further the verbs ἀποστέλλω (apostelló) and πέμπω (pempó) appear to used almost interchangeably, sometimes in adjacent verses.

Interestingly, John 5:23 offers compelling evidence of the equality of Jesus and the Father: *that all may honor the Son just as they honor the Father. Whoever does not honor the Son does not honor the Father, who sent him.*  Ellicot succinctly observes:

> The purpose of the entire commission of judgment to the Son, a
>   bestowment which illustrates the quickening results that he (who does
>   the will of the Father) wills to effect, is now gathered to a lofty
>   climax, abundantly vindicating the right he had claimed to call God
>   his own Father. It is as follows, in order that all may honour the
>   Son. Τιμῶσιν, not προσκυνῶσιν ("honour," not "worship"), is the word
>   used; but seeing that the identical sentiment of reverence due to the
>   Supreme Being, to the Father, is that which is here said to be due to
>   the Son, and is here declared to be the reason why all judgment is
>   entrusted to the issues of his will, - we are at a loss to know how
>   loftier attributes could be ascribed to the Son.

I agree.  Perhaps John was at pains to make things more explicit to counter the (then) rising tide various isms that deprecated the status of Jesus.  John ensures that Jesus is not just God (John 1:1-3), but "the God" (ho theos), John 20:28; about which Ellicott observes:

> **My Lord and my God**.--These words are preceded by "said unto him," and are followed by "because thou hast seen Me, thou hast believed;"
>   and the words "my Lord" can only be referred to Christ. (Comp. John
>   20:13.) The sentence cannot therefore, without violence to the
>   context, be taken as an exclamation addressed to God, and is to be
>   understood in the natural meaning of a confession by the Apostle that
>   his Lord was also God.